# TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable while creating new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization

i am trying to create new dataframe from my existing data and i am getting this error . i have checked all the grammatical and syntatical erros .how to fix this error

```
teams = data['toss_winner'].unique()
decision_making = pd.DataFrame([],columns=['Toss Winner','Decision','Times'])

for id,element in enumerate(teams):
    temp_data = data[data(['toss winner']==element) & (data['toss_decision']=='bat')]
    temp_data = data[data(['toss winner']==element) & (data['toss_decision']=='field')]

    decision_making = decision_making.append({'Toss Winner':element,
                                              'Decison':'bat','Times': temp_bat['toss_winner'].count()},ignore_index=True)
    decision_making = decision_making.append({'Toss Winner':element,
                                              'Decison':'field','Times': temp_bat['toss_winner'].count()},ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: `decision_making.append` return None. you don't need to perform set operation `(decision_making = decision_making.append(something))` . It will make your `decision_making = None`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you missed some syntax error. You used parenthesis after `data[data`.

```
for id,element in enumerate(teams):
    temp_data = data[(data['toss winner']==element) & (data['toss_decision']=='bat')] 
    temp_data = data[(data['toss winner']==element) & (data['toss_decision']=='field')]
```